# InfluxDB Adding an Extra Column for Data Visualisation

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

Good Evening,

I have recently started using InfluxDB Cloud but having a lot of issues visualising data,

I am wanting on the Y axis to show the Time and then on the Y Axis the Speed(MPH) from a certain range from like 0-80 but I can't seem to be able to select the Speed for the X Column I have attached some screenshots to better help you understand Thanks!

[This shows you the issues im facing with the X And Y Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8B6V.png)

[As this photo shows i want the _value to be on the X Value to show a maximum range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7fMM.png)

Comment: Please add an excerpt of the Raw Data and your query. As code, and not as a screenshot too

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your data is on different tables as you can see the column table index on the left in the second image. So in graph mode, you see only one point in the graph.
Try to update your CSV file to import to InfluxDB and update the table column to the same like this:

```
result,table,_start,_stop,_time,region,host,_value
my-result,0,2018-05-08T20:50:00Z,2018-05-08T20:51:00Z,2018-05-08T20:50:00Z,east,A,15.43
my-result,0,2018-05-08T20:50:00Z,2018-05-08T20:51:00Z,2018-05-08T20:50:20Z,east,B,59.25
my-result,0,2018-05-08T20:50:00Z,2018-05-08T20:51:00Z,2018-05-08T20:50:40Z,east,C,52.62
```

Comment: Hi there, I am not using CSV to import to InfluxDB I am using node-red to feed data from a sensor directly into influxdb and then InfluxDB is storing it as that any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you write down some points that you pushed to InfluxDB ?